# Node.js application exits without throwing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios

I'm experiencing a weird issue with nodejs, my application quits without throwing any error or logging anything into the console. The whole code runs in a while (true) loop, I checked all of the if/else and try/catch blocks and the code never has a reason to stop, in fact this happens after running for some hours without any issue.

I've also tried adding a general error handler on the main function of the application like this:

```js
try {
    start()
} catch(err) {
    utils.logMessage(`General Error: ${err}`, 'red')
    utils.sendErrorWebhook(err)
}
```

It didn't change anything though, and when checking logs everything runs smooth and then suddenly stops.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue or know how to fix? Main modules I'm using are the mongodb official client (not mongoose) and axios.

Comment: Welcome! This is not nearly enough for anyone to help you. What does start do for example? Node will exit if nothing is keeping it open. Please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs i've updated my post, let me know if you need any more details :)

Comment: Please include more code in your question as it appears that node may be exiting because of ram allocation. But we cannot be sure because your code snippet is short